# Two representations with a common irreducible component

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field. Let $\widetilde M$ be the subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{F}_q)$ consisting of [block diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) such that the main-diagonal blocks are invertible matrices. Let $M=\widetilde M\cap SL(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$. Suppose $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are irreducible representations of $\widetilde M$ such that their restrictions to $M$ have a common irreducible component. Can we show that $\sigma_1\simeq\sigma_2\chi$ for some character $\chi$?

---

I am learning Mackey theory and the answer may require some induction-restriction arguments. Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define a block diagonal matrix? According to [the definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices), every element of $GL(n,\mathbb F_q)$ is a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the definition on Wikipedia. According to that definition, $\widetilde M\simeq GL_{n_1}(\mathbb{F}_q)\times GL_{n_2}(\mathbb{F}_q)\times\dots GL_{n_r}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ where $n=n_1+n_2+\dots+n_r$

Comment: But that’s all of $GL(n,\mathbb F_q)$ for $r=1$. The article explicitly states that “Any square matrix can trivially be considered a block diagonal matrix with only one block”.